# Local homeomorphism between two spaces:

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

If $M$ and $N$ are Hausdorff spaces, $f:M→N$ is a local homeomorphism, $M$ is compact and non empty, and $N$ is connected, is $f$ a surjective map?

I have an idea: If $f$ is a local homeomorphism then then $f$ is continuous and open map.  Since $M$ is both open and closed in itself $f(M)$ is open in $N$ . And as $M$ is compact,it's image under $f$ is compact, since $f$ is continuous. Now since $N$ is hausdorff every compact set is closed . Therefore $f(M) $ is both open and closed in $N$ . As $N$ is connected therefore only possibility of $f(M)=N$. Hence $f$ is surjective map.

Is my argument okay?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I have used the fact f is a local homeomorphism. In the question it is given that $f$ is just a local homeomorphism. And a map is local homeomorphism implies this is continuous and open map. Using the definition of local Homeomorphism We need to prove that $f$ is open and continuous.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_homeomorphism
I am using this definition of local homeomorphism.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I have one doubt if f is local homeomorphism but X is a singleton set then how it is open map ??

Comment: Basically my confusion is in definition of local homeomorphism.

Comment: @Spectrum according to the definition of local homeomorphism, $f$ has to induce a homeomorphism $f_{|U}:U\to f(U)$. But read the definition closely: **$f(U)$ is assumed to be open**. So if $X$ is a singleton, then $U=X$ and $f(U)$ is an open point in $N$. It is isolated. And since $N$ is connected, then $N$ is singleton as well. And everything is fine.

Comment: I got your point.